# Matrix - link to specific item in row

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

I have a P&T matrix field with a series of cells: images/title/dimensions/date/price

I display all the images in a row and if I click on the image I would like to go to a single entry page that shows ONLY that one image with the other cells (title/date etc)

Is this possible or am I better off makeing each row it's own entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an add-on called [Matrix URL Title](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/matrix-url-title), also from P&T, that would allow you to do something like this.  It would involve some conditionals in your template, as you might expect, but I've done it before.  Worth a look anyway if your user entry flow makes more sense as a matrix rather than a new channel entry per row.

Answer (score 2):

Great question! In my experience, when you need a specific page for content like this, while Matrix is tempting, it is far more efficient (and easier) to create a new channel and/or channel entry.